# css flex-wrap flex-basis are not enough

Tags: css

I have a div container which has 5 div as child. what i want to do is, i want the last child goes to the next line even if there are enough space to stay at the first line. the reason i want this is i am applying some CSS for smaller screens so i dont want to change the html.

like:

---a--- ---b--- ---c--- ---d--- ---e---

to be:

---a--- ---b--- ---c--- ---d---

```
      ---e---
```

I have tried the flex-basis 100% but it will increase the width to 100%. i want to keep the size as it is and it remains at the center.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the small amount of information provided, and no source code, I have attempted to recreate your issue and provide a solution.  If this doesn't work for your situation, I recommend you edit your question to provide a minimal, reproducible example for others to solve.

html:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="sub-div">--a--</div>
  <div class="sub-div">--b--</div>
  <div class="sub-div">--c--</div>
  <div class="sub-div">--d--</div>
  <div class="sub-div">--e--</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent-div {
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-div {
  display: inline;
}

.sub-div:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg8smdy5/

Comment: thank you my friend, I am new to this concept and i will remember to provide more details in the future.